# Out of the box data form / view web without Sharepoint Designer

Tags: data-view-web-part, out-of-the-box

Is there any out of the box data form / view web part available, which can be loaded without SharePoint designer?

I'm using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Dataview web parts are "out of the box" but in the sense SharePoint Designer knows how to put them on a page and lets you build them. They are totally configurable and customizable depending on your skill level.

You need SharePoint Designer to build dataview web parts.

Comment: And without SPD? Is there any alternative?

Comment: You'd have to use Visual Studio to create one or use something like Notepad++ to create your own .webpart file that could be uploaded to a site.

Comment: Any useful site with sample "*.webpart"s?